# Two Tables in alv

Tags: abap

I am having two tables `BKPF` and `TOA01`.

1. Report should have the following selection screen fields.
   Company code(`BUKRS`), Document Number(`BELNR`), Fiscal Year(`GJAHR`)
2. For ALV report following field should be available in the layout.

   BKPF-BUKRS

   BKPF-BELNR

   BKPF-GJAHR

   BKPF-USNAM

   TOA01-ARCHIV_ID

   TOA01-ARC_DOC_ID

   **Link between BKPF and TOA01:
   TOA01-SAP_OBJECT = 'BKPF'
   AND
   TOA01-OBJECT_ID = concatenate -> BKPF-BUKRS + BKPF-BELNR + BKPF-GJAHR.

I want the logic to display (the alv) using two given tables using the link between them (given above).

Please help me with the answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you familiar with ABAP-CDS, you can define two CDS-views. The first one
contains the data from table BKPF:

```
define view zbooking_doc as select from bkpf {
  key bukrs,
  key belnr,
  key gjahr,
  usnam,
  concat(bukrs, belnr, gjahr) as archiv_object_id
```

}

The second CDS-View joins BKPF with table TOA01 (according to your condition TOA01-SAP_OBJECT = 'BKPF' AND TOA01-OBJECT_ID = concatenate -> BKPF-BUKRS + BKPF-BELNR + BKPF-GJAHR.):

```
define view zbooking_doc_and_archiv as select from zbooking_doc
  left outer join toa01 on toa01.object_id = zbooking_doc.archiv_object_id {
  key bukrs,
  key belnr,
  key gjahr,
  usnam,
  archiv_id,
  arc_doc_id
} where toa01.sap_object = 'BKPF'
```

The tables shown in the ALV can be filled with a select-statement on view `zbooking_doc_and_archiv`.